# A way to represent a transition function in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, dfa, nfa

I'm writing a project that converts a Nondeterministic Finite Automaton to an equivalent Deterministic Finite Automaton. So far, I have my NFA.java superclass and subclasses for the NFA's states, alphabet, start state and accept states with their respective methods for conversion. So far my NFA.java class looks like this

```
class NFA {

    NFAStates statesNFA;
    NFAAlphabet alphabetNFA;
    NFASState startstateNFA;
    NFAAcceptStates acceptstatesNFA;

}
```

My NFAStates.java, NFAAlphabet.java, and NFAAcceptStates.java are LinkedHashSets of strings which are parsed in from an array from user input. My NFASState.java class is an array containing a single character.

I'm trying to find a way to accurately store the transition function (grid which shows which states go to which upon certain input). Is there a way I can do this, perhaps with an n-dimentional array? I also need to be able to manipulate this object with methods into a DFA.

Comment: One way would be to have an array, list or set of NFASState on the NFASState class itself to represent all possible transitions from that state.

Comment: @maraca Wow that's a great idea, thank you. Do you think it would be better to have that in NFAStates to represrnt all transition arrows from each state?

Answer (score 3):

More generally what you are asking is how to represent a network with nodes and directed edges between them. In your case the nodes are states and the edges are transitions. So I'll use your terms in the answer below but you could just as easily use nodes and edges, cities and roads etc.

You have many options, depending on various characteristics of your problems space. These are assuming the transitions do not have characteristics (such as cost, pre-conditions etc.) but if they do then minor alterations of the models will support storing those characteristics.

1. Store the transitions with the states:

> ```
> class State {
>     private Set<State> transitions;
> }
> ```

2. Store transitions in a separate class

> ```
> class Transition {
>     private State from;
>     private State to;
> }
>
> Set<Transition> transitions;
> ```

3. Have a map from each state to the allowed next states

> ```
> Map<State, List<State>> transitions;
> ```

4. Have an array of booleans representing whether each state change is allowed (assuming each state has an id that can be used to index into the array).

> ```
> boolean[][] transitions;
> ```

Which of these you choose will depend on the algorithm you will use for your transition from NFA to DFA. I suspect it'll be easier if the transitions are not inside the state so that probably rules option 1 out. But the reset are all probably viable for you. Just pick the one that fits best with your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

What about a class to hold the transition?

```
interface NFATransition {
    NFAState apply(NFAState currentState, Object input);
}

public class SimpleNFATransition implements NFATransition {
    private final NFAState fromState;
    private final NFAState toState;
    private final Object transitionOnInput;

    public SimpleNFATransition(NFAState fromState, NFAState toState, Object transitionOnInput) {
        this.fromState = fromState;
        this.toState = toState;
        this.transitionOnInput = transitionOnInput;
    }

    public NFAState apply(NFAState fromState, Object input) {
        if (fromState.equals(this.fromState) && input.equals(transitionOnInput)) {
            return toState;
        } else {
            return fromState;
        }
    }
}
```

Enumerate your transitions in an array or a list.

```
NFATransition[] transitions = new NFATransition[]{ new SimpleNFATransition(...), ... }
```

Then when executing the machine, do something like:

```
NFAState currentState = startstateNFA;
while (!currentState.equals(stopState)) {
    for (NFATransition transition : transitions) {
        currentState = transition.apply(currentState, input);
        if (currentState.equals(stopState)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```